# insert variables in react-markdown

Tags: reactjs, variables, markdown

I have a text in markdown and I want to display it in my react-app with variables.

I tried this way :

```
<ReactMarkdown
   children={contentMd}
   renderers={{
     someElement: {
     instanceLabel: label,
     sessionName: test,
     mail: emailSupport,
     adresse: adressePostale,
                  },
             }}
 />
```

and in my text in markdown I refer the variables like that :

```
outil de gestion par {{instanceLabel}}
```

But it doesn't work...

Does someone has a solution?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`contentMd` is a `string`, not JSX. You need to interpolate variables, for example this way:

```
<ReactMarkdown
  children={`outil de gestion par ${instanceLabel}`}
  {...props}
/>
```

Or like so:

```
<ReactMarkdown
  {...props}
>
  {`outil de gestion par ${instanceLabel}`}
</ReactMarkdown>
```

Comment: OK thanks !!
But I shortened the text of contentMd, it's a long text that the user can edit in an other page. this is why i want to inject the values of the variables in this render